# Does the forgetful functor $F:\mathrm{CAlg}\to\mathrm{Alg}^{(1)}$ sending $E_\infty$-ring spectra to $E_1$-ring spectra preserve limits and colimits?

Tags: homotopy-theory, higher-algebra, ring-spectra

In remark 7.1.0.4. of Lurie's [Higher Algebra](https://www.math.ias.edu/%7Elurie/papers/HA.pdf), the sequence $(E_n^{\otimes})_{0\leq n\leq\infty}$ of $\infty$-operads induces forgetful functors for the sequence of categories $(\operatorname{Alg}^{(n)}(\mathrm{Sp}))_{0\leq n\leq\infty}$ of $E_n$-rings. Do these forgetful functors preserve limits and colimits?

Comment: Forgetful functors preserve small limits and *sifted* colimits. Not all small colimits, e.g. they do not preserve finite coproducts.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. Could you give a reference for this result?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Limit-preservation is the content of section 3.2.2 of Higher Algebra (see particularly Corollary 3.2.2.5). Preservation of sifted colimits is in section 3.2.3 (see particularly Corollary 3.2.3.2).

As Z. M [points out](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/463656/does-the-forgetful-functor-fcalg-to-alg1-sending-e-infty-ring-spectra#comment1203797_463656), coproducts are not preserved. This is parallel with ordinary algebra: the coproduct of $\Bbb Z[x]$ and $\Bbb Z[y]$ in the category of commutative rings is $\Bbb Z[x,y]$, whereas the coproduct in the category of associative rings is the noncommutative polynomial algebra $\Bbb Z\langle x,y\rangle$.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer with examples! I will try to understand these results with your hints.